# Increasing width in tufte handout eliminates running title

Tags: header-footer, tufte

If I use the `textwidth` argument to increase the size of the main text in the tufte-handout, it makes the running title run off the page.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=.7\paperwidth}
\title[Running title]{This is the title of my handout}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to be able to have the full width, but with the running header. This is the output from the above code, but with the  `\geometry{textwidth=0.7\paperwidth}` line commented out:

[image]

How can I use the `textwidth` argument but maintain the running title and page numbering of the tufte-handout class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust the `marginparwidth` along with `textwidth` otherwise the total text width will exceed the paper width.

Use this instead:

```
\newgeometry{left=0.12\paperwidth,top=1in,headsep=2\baselineskip,
    textwidth=0.7\paperwidth,marginparsep=1ex,marginparwidth=0.1\paperwidth,
    textheight=44\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip}
```

Remember that `tufte` already loads `geometry`, hence you won't need to add `\usepackage{geometry}`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\newgeometry{left=0.12\paperwidth,top=1in,headsep=2\baselineskip,
    textwidth=0.7\paperwidth,marginparsep=1ex,marginparwidth=0.1\paperwidth,
    textheight=44\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip}


\title[Running title]{This is the title of my handout}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Adjust the parameters inside `\newgeometry` as suitable so that `left + textwidth + marginparsep + marginparwidth` doesn't exceed the paper width.

[image]